# how can i rewrite my url for only certain pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How can I use .htaccess to rewrite URL for certain pages only?

For example, I want it to work on index.php but not the rest of the pages on the site or on all pages but index.php.

I run in to issues with sub domains and php scripts where the URL redirecting that I am using will mess up stuff. Below is an example of the kind of script I want to use.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php/?node=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your question gives some information, but is not enough. If you are asking, is because the rule set in the question doesn't work, so that is not of any help. Post some complete URLs examples, don't expect people to guess what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass URL as REQUEST_URI server variable:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(your_url)$
RewriteRule %1 do_some_stuff
```

As an example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php$
RewriteRule %1 - [F]
```

Or just pass it in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ do_some_stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check out `RewriteCond` (conditions) for .htaccess
Check http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ for a lot of information and examples.

You could also write a rule just for index.php and then flag it as the last rule `[l]`

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php(.*)   /index.php$1  [L]
RedirectRule ^/(.*)$   /index.php?path=$1  [L]
```